# Set 1280 x 1024 resolution for secondary monitor

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, resolution, intel-graphics

I'm using old Dell Latitude E5420 laptop win Windows 10. Trying to set resolution for my plug-n-play monitor (Samsung SyncMaster 713n). But found only unsupported set of resolutions:

[image]

Display adapter - Intel Graphics 3000

Why there are no such popular resolution 1280x1024? How to solve this problem?

Comment: What type of display connector are you using to connect the monitor?

Comment: Have you verified that your graphics drivers are up to date? Also, is this the drop-down list a sizable with the external monitor selected? You've only shown the drop-down, not the rest of the settings window.